# Produce two pdf of different length from single source file

Tags: compiling

I am writing a journal paper which is roughly 15 pages long. Out of this journal paper, I would also like to make a conference version which should be 5 pages long.

**My question is**: Is it possible to only work with one latex file and produce two pdf of different length?   For example, can I select a text and specify that it goes to the long version only?

Comment: If you can obtain a conference version by only selecting material from longest version (Is it really possible?!), you can use `comment` package.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke  Would this also create two version of the document?

Comment: No. It is possible to have 2 versions in one document and switch them, but it is nearly impossible to say anything without additional information.

Comment: If the paper will be circulated as PDF (rather than merely as "paper") then you would also have to change the metadata. That could be very tricky, especially because many PDF readers will not show you all the metadata, so you might not be able to check your work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible solution:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newif\iffullversion
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\jobname}{short}{\fullversionfalse}{\fullversiontrue}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]
\iffullversion
\kant[3-14]
\else
\kant[12-13]
\fi
\end{document}
```

Compile the short version with `pdflatex -jobname short`. This is easily converted to using the `comment` package, if you prefer that over plain style `\if` commands. Or you can use the boolean features of the `etoolbox` package, since we're already using it.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: Is it possible to only work with one latex file and produce two pdf of different length?

You could split you single `*.tex` file into multiple files having selected portions of the document.

You could have two different *master* files where one includes all sub files and the other a sub set only. This could be done by using either standard `\input{subfile.tex}` or `\include{subfile.tex}` command or using the *subfiles* package.