# Generate two pdf files from a single beamer source

Tags: beamer

I get normal beamer pdf file without any option, `\documentclass[]{beamer}`, but I add handout option to get different file `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`. I modify the beamer source and compile twice to get these two normal and handout beamer files, but I want to automatize it.

How can I do it? How can I have one beamer source that has a different option from a command line?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. The answer is: use two wrappers, both inputting the body of the document. I'd illustrate if I didn't have to start from scratch. Then you just compile the relevant one. If you really need a single file, you can conditionalise on `\jobname`, I think, but that strikes me as unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: If you *do* want to go the `jobname` route, look at my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408632/1424).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\jobname` solved this issue. This is the code. The default option is without `handout` option.

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\jobname}{handout}{\documentclass[handout]{beamer}}{\documentclass[]{beamer}}

\begin{document}

\title[A]{A}
\author{A} 
\date{Spring Semester, 2018} 

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Hello}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello1 \pause
    \item Hello2
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This configuration makes the script that makes the beamer output with and without handout option easy.

```
pdflatex -jobname handout jobname.tex
mv handout.pdf jobname-handout.pdf
pdflatex jobname.tex
```